# Trouble in running julia on cluster

Tags: julia, cluster-computing, slurm

I am running some simulations on a SLURM cluster with julia. I am novice in julia and can't seem to figure out what is missing. I have three main codefiles "job.sh", "main.jl" and "run-experiments.jl" and a proejct.toml and Manifest.toml file in the same directory. In "Job.sh", I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=RunDMRG
#SBATCH --nodes=4
#SBATCH --oversubscribe
#SBATCH --time=08:00:00
#SBATCH --output=output_%j.txt
#SBATCH --error=error_%j.txt
#SBATCH --account=myname

module load julia

julia -e 'import Pkg; Pkg.instantiate()'  # Install packages

julia main.jl 256 100
```

and the main.jl file contains :

```
using ITensors
using Plots
using Printf
using Statistics
using LaTeXStrings
using CSV

using Pkg; Pkg.instantiate()
include("run-experiments.jl")

disorder = [10.0^i for i in -4:1]
nsites = parse(Int, ARGS[1]) 
nrealizations = parse(Int, ARGS[2]) 
print("Starting...")

main(nsites, nrealizations, disorder)
```

where the function `main()` is contained in `run-experiments.jl`.

When I submit the job, I immediately get an error stating that "iTensor is not installed". More specifically, the error file says :

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package ITensors not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("ITensors")` to install the ITensors package.

Stacktrace:
 [1] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:893
in expression starting at /scratch/zt1/project/main.jl:1
```

But isn't that what Pkg.instantiate() is supposed to do? Would appreciate any help on how to resolve this and run a clean simulation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Julia uses the built-in environment and package system `Pkg.jl`. These environments are encoded in the `Project.toml` and `Manifest.toml` files, but in order to use them, you have to switch to / `activate` the environment that you want to use. The first time you do this on a new system, `instantiate` makes sure that all packages that are listed in the environment are installed. So, you don't necessarily always need the `instantiate` in your Slurm script or Julia script, but instead, your Julia script should start with

```
import Pkg
Pkg.activate(".") # or the actual path to the folder where your Enviromentment is
```

This is just a very short explaination, and if you are not familiar with `Pkg` and the environment system, you should really have a look at the documentation: https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/getting-started/